# What are the types of hair in latin?

Tags: english-to-latin-translation, vocabulary, adjective

What would be the adjectives to describe someone's hair?
The only I know is "crispus" "curled"
Could i just translate the adjectives in English into latin?
Straight hair= capillus rectus
Wavy hair=capillus undulatus
Long/short hair=capillus longus/curtus

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Straight hair can indeed be called ***capillus directus***, as you can see from this passage in Vitruvius (not necessarily your first stop when looking for hair vocabulary), [*De Architectura* 6, 1.3](https://www.thelatinlibrary.com/vitruvius/vitruvius6.html#1.3):

> Ex eo quoque, <quae> sub septentrionibus nutriuntur gentes, inmanibus corporibus, candidis coloribus, **derecto capillo** et rufo, oculis caesis, sanguine multo ab umoris plenitate caelique refrigerationibus sunt conformati; qui autem sunt proximi ad axem meridianum subiectique solis cursui, brevioribus corporibus, colore fusco, **crispo capillo,** oculis nigris, cruribus validis, sanguine exiguo solis impetu perficiuntur.

(*Derectus* is a collateral form.) I'll spare you Vitrivius' pet theory why this is so, but the people living in colder northerly climates presumably have straight hair, while those living in the southern sun have curly hair. It stands to reason that *rectus* would also be understood. (Also, cf. *tonsi rectique capilli*, [Iuv. Sat. 11, 149](https://www.thelatinlibrary.com/juvenal/11.shtml).) Additionally, hair can be ***densus*** or ***rarus***.

I do not think *capillus undulatus* would work, as that word seems to have been used of clothes only.

Long hair can indeed be ***longus***, but also ***promissus***, as *capillum promittere* means to let your hair grow (analogous also *barbam promittere* by the way). Someone having long hair is also ***comatus*** (from the defective verb [*comare*](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.04.0059%3Aentry%3Dcomo2); hence also ***comans***). Short hair generally seems to be ***tonsus*** (cut), and ***intonsus*** (uncut) also occurs.

Comment: Thank you, Sebastian.